# How to get element by xpath and inner text?

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to locate a UI popup using xpath and inner text. The popup html is like this:

```
Hello ? {some elements} What would you like to do today {more elements} Play or Die ? {Yes button, No button}.
```

I want to get this element by using something like this:

//div[contains(@innerText, 'Hello ? What would you like to do today Play or Die ?')]

How do I do this ? Or is there a better way to find this popup ? There are no Ids or permanent classes here. Moreover the DOM structure is variable.

Comment: will appreciate a vote-up on the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use xpath ver2's matches function:

```
//div[matches(text(), 'Hello ?\w+ What would you like to do today \w+')]
```

Which allows regex.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the interleaving elements contain no inner text, you can use `.` instead of `@innerText` to get concatenation of all text nodes within context element (the `div` in this case). Combine `.` with `normalize-space()` to remove leading and trailing whitespace characters, as well as to normalize consecutive whitespace characters into single space. With `normalize-space()` the `.` can be removed as it is the default parameter :

```
//div[contains(normalize-space(), 'Hello ? What would you like to do today Play or Die ?')]
```