# Selecting a ClassName using Selenium, where there are multiple ClassNames with the same name

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to select a button on a site where the className is the same for multiple elements and the thing that differentiates each one is the header tag.

Right now I have this

```
    button = browser.find_element_by_class_name('start')
    button.click()
```

On the webpage there are 2 buttons which are defined as the below

```
<h4 class="start">1:48pm</h4>
<h4 class="start">3:54pm</h4>
```

I am trying to specify my script to select based on the time within the header tags of the start class.Is there a way to do that using Selenium and Python?

Comment: See https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/css-selector-selenium-locator-selenium-tutorial-6/ , https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors eg.

Comment: maybe this will be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146296/how-to-get-element-by-xpath-and-inner-text/44148196#44148196

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. If they have a difference xpath, you can traverse from their parent. If you want to click one or another button, you can get each button time and compare them (I have never tried this before but I think this is possible)

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath and select the index of the correct element. Notice we are using
`find_elements_...` instead of `find_element_...`.

```
button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//h4[@class="start"]')[1].click()
```